# Text processing of unix file

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, string

I have following data in a unix flatfile and I want to suppress duplicate values in first two columns and convert it as shown below:

```
1:x:4:3:2:y
1:x:7:9:l:z
1:0:3:j:k:m
2:9:r:s:6:u
2:m:y:5:7:9
2:u:7:9:7:6
3:a:b:c:d:e
3:a:b:d:e:f
3:a:b:n:r:s
```

To:

```
1:x:4:3:2:y
 : :7:9:l:z
 :0:3:j:k:m
2:9:r:s:6:u
 :m:y:5:7:9
 :u:7:9:7:6
3:a:b:c:d:e
 : :b:d:e:f
 : :b:n:r:s
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I might help you if you are allowed to use Ruby programming language... Is that allowed?

Comment: @s.goswami yes  pls go ahead

Comment: bash-4.4$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
bash-4.4$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [sparcv9-solaris2.11]
bash-4.4$

Comment: Are you only concerned with _consecutive_ duplicates, or would an `x` in column 2 in a line further down also be deleted?

Comment: I am overwhelmed. ruby I see for the first time - hope it can be made clerarer; like that awk script. I perfectly understand it _without_ understanding, thank you ;) Together with the visual effect  shown in the Q! (I would take perl for this, just somehow, same technique as in that `awk` one liner. _That_ is a one liner!)

Comment: @Kusalananda i am only concerned about the duplicates , in column 1 and column 2 , i want empty space for duplicate value , i still need delimiter : separating  co1 , col2

Answer (score 3):

Straightforwardly with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F':' '++a[$1] > 1{ $1=" " }++b[$2] > 1{ $2=" " }1' OFS=':' inp_file
1:x:4:3:2:y
 : :7:9:l:z
 :0:3:j:k:m
2:9:r:s:6:u
 :m:y:5:7:9
 :u:7:9:7:6
3:a:b:c:d:e
 : :b:d:e:f
 : :b:n:r:s
```

Comment: bash-4.4$ awk -F':' '++a[$1] > 1{ $1=" " }++b[$2] > 1{ $2=" " }1' OFS=':' Array_e.log 
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
bash-4.4$

Comment: @Naga, post your awk version

Comment: that will also show an extra line like `3:x:b:n:r:s` at the end with `x` being a duplicate of the `a` above it. I'm not sure that's what's intended -- it's hard to say based on the OP.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest . how to find awk version ?   awk --version hangs                              bash-4.4$   which awk
/usr/bin/awk
bash-4.4$ /usr/bin/awk --version

Comment: @Naga, and what's the output of `/usr/bin/awk --version` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest                                                                                                                      bash-4.4$ /usr/bin/awk -V
^C
bash-4.4$ /usr/bin/awk -v

^C
bash-4.4$ 
bash-4.4$ /usr/bin/awk -version
^C
bash-4.4$ /usr/bin/awk --version
^C
bash-4.4$

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest .                                                                                                                bash-4.4$ which awk
/usr/bin/awk
bash-4.4$

Answer (score 0):

As @Naga mentioned in the comments that a Ruby script is allowed. Here I have came up with a solution.

### Ruby Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# Frozen_String_Literal: false
$-v = nil
d, $-s, i, $,, $; = [], ?\s.freeze, '', ?:.freeze, ?:.freeze
::FILENAME = $*[0] || abort("Pass the filename as Argument.\nExample:\n\t#{File.basename($0)} hello.rb")

puts IO.readlines(File.join(Dir.pwd, FILENAME)).map! { |x|
    c = x.tap(&:strip!).split
    d.clear && i.replace(c[0].to_s) if i != c[0]
    a = c.first(2).map { |y| d.find { |z| z.include?(y) } ? $-s : y }.join << $, << c.drop(2).join unless c.empty?
    d << c.first(2).join
    a
} rescue exit!
```

### Running

```
ruby scriptname.rb inputfile.txt
```

### Output

[Assuming inputfile.txt contains the same data in the question]

```
1:x:4:3:2:y
 : :7:9:l:z
 :0:3:j:k:m
2:9:r:s:6:u
 :m:y:5:7:9
 :u:7:9:7:6
3:a:b:c:d:e
 : :b:d:e:f
 : :b:n:r:s
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: ruby script is working fine, but i have challenge                                                                          1:x,a:4:3:2:y
1:x,1:7:9:l:z
1:0,2:3:j:k:m
2:9:r:s:6:u
2:m:y:5:7:9
2:u,1:7:9:7:6
3:a:b:c:d:e
3:a,2:b:d:e:f
3:a,1:b:n:r:s

Comment: is that space splitted instead of new line characters?

Comment: I have edited the answer so that if the given file doesn't exist (or for any other error), it will exit with return value 1. Also, the script will not raise errors for invalid files...